# How to redirect to another URL if query string match?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I want to redirect www.domain.com/index.php?id=xx to www.anotherURL.com

If the id=xx match then redirect the URL. Is there any PHP or JavaScript code for this? If both are not then htaccess?

Comment: _php_ has `$_GET`, _JavaScript_ has `window.location.search`

Comment: `http_redirect()`  wrap it in an `if` statement

Comment: Welcome to SO please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here

Comment: can you write the full code or the code source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *really* have tried this yourself first, but in PHP it's pretty basic

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    if($_GET['id'] == xx){
        header('Location: http://www.anotherURL.com');
        exit ();
    }
}
?>
```

Substitute `xx` for whatever you want to test the `id` against.

Comment: Wow! i really need this. and it works... thanks <3

Comment: Scott, don't forget that a `Location` header needs to be followed by an `exit()`, otherwise the race condition bugs you'll get will take ages to debug!

Comment: Ah yes, I'll edit this to reflect

Answer (score 0):

you can make file url.php

```
<?php
$id=$_GET["id"];
if($id=="xx"){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
?>
```

then you include in your index.php

```
<?php
    include("url.php")
?>
```

so if you have many page you don't need to copy paste here and there.

Comment: If `id` doesn't appear in the query string, this will produce index errors.

Comment: you can filter _GET using isset function.